# How to convert user input from search field to specific MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, search

My question is simple, but I cannot find the answer.

How to make PHP search in which user's input in the search field in a shape of two or more words, separated by special characters, is translated to specific MySQL search query? I will try to explain by examples.

Example 1:

A user enters: `word1 + word2` and sends a query in which both words are searched as a phrase (`"word1 word2"`) (something like double-quoted search in Google)

Example 2:

A user enters: `word1 - word2` and sends a query in which both words are searched in succession, with 0 or more words between (`word1 word2`, `word1 word(n) word2`, but no `word2 word1` or `word2 word(n) word2`)

Example 3:

A user enters: `# - word` and sends a query and gets results only from database cells where string begins with `word`.

There are also more examples (combinations of those above, and with more words searched) but if I get help with these, I think I will figure out the rest.

Comment: Any implementations? It's just as easy as creating queries dynamically for each case you need to process. You will need `LIKE`, `AND`, `OR`, `IN`... I think you'll be ok even with only `LIKE` + `%` / `.` / `_`

Comment: You need to provide a tag to your question, showing which extension you are using for the database access - PDO, or mysqli.

Comment: I am using mysqli extension.

Comment: Sorry AndrewShmig, I am new in the field, what you mean by implementation?